# laravel component class was ignored

Tags: php, laravel

I made a laravel component using command `php artisan make:component TestComponent`

So, two files(`resources/view/component/test-component.blade.php` and `app/View/Components/TestComponent.php`) was created.

However, `test-component.blade.php` file was worked fine, but `TestComponent.php` file was ignored.

I check this issue to change render method like that.

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class TestComponent extends Component
{
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $id;
    
    public function __construct($id="test")
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.foofoofoofoofoo'); // fake view name
    }
}
```

The fake view name(foofoofoofoofoo) was ignored and test-component view was rendered.

And id variable doesn't delivered to view when I use default value like `<x-test-component />`
(`<x-test-component id='abc' />` was worked fine.)

I try to register manually in boot method on `AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::component('test-component', App\View\Components\TestComponent::class);
    }
```

But it doesn't work too.

`php artisan clear:view`, `php artisan cache:clear`, `composer dump` doesn't work on this issue.

Comment: Where do you pass `id` and where does call `TestComponent`? Please share

Comment: @A.ANoman TestComponent called automatically by laravel when test-component was used.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem to update laravel version to 8.38.0 and run `php artisan view:clear`

Comment: Good to see your self effort.